# selectize.js : Specifying json object child proiperties as searchField

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

I am following `selectize.js` for angular as given in http://machineboy2045.github.io/angular-selectize/

The JSON array used as options is an array of objects of the structure

```
{ id:'001',
name:{firstName:'aaa',lastName:'bbb'},
remarks:'ffsaghas'
.....}
```

I tried specfiying config as

```
  $scope.myConfig = {
       valueField: 'id',
       searchField:['name.firstName'],
  ...............}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. However giving `id` or `remarks` as search fields works perfectly. I guess may be because name is again an object.
How to resolve this issue?

Comment: @mnille  ..thank you for formatting..

Comment: I found this: https://github.com/selectize/selectize.js/pull/1126

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `nesting: true` as an option for sifter(in `selectize.js`) helped.
Thank you @Timo.

Comment: How exactly does the config look like with the sifter part?